# Simple PHP search in Database won't bring up result

Tags: php, mysql, search, chef-recipe

I am building a recipe database with some of my friends and for that we need our users to be able to search within our site. Our database consists of 3 tables:

recipes - **recipe_id** (*primary key*), **recipe_name**

ingredients - **ingredient_id** (*primary key*), **ingredient_name**

recipe_ingredients - **ingredient_id** (*foreign key*), **recipe_id** (*foreign key*)

We want to be able to search the recipe_ingredients for a recipe or ingredient name and have our site show every ingredient connected to that recipe or every recipe connected to that ingredient. And so we made this query:

```
select ingredient_name, recipe_name, recipe_ingredients.*
from recipe_ingredients
inner join ingredients inner join recipes
on recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients.ingredient_id
and recipe_ingredients.recipe_id = recipes.recipe_id

WHERE ingredient_name = 'Brød';
```

Which works fine for us. However, putting it into our search function in php, it gives 'There were no search results!' back every single time no matter what we searched. Here is the code. Would someone point out the mistake we made?

```
$output = '';
if (isset($_POST['work'])) {
 $searchq = $_POST['work'];
 $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
 $query = mysql_query 

  ("select ingredient_name, recipe_name, recipe_ingredients.*
  from recipe_ingredients
  inner join ingredients inner join recipes
  on recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients.ingredient_id
  and recipe_ingredients.recipe_id = recipes.recipe_id
  WHERE ingredient_name LIKE '%searchq%' or recipe_name LIKE '%searchq%'")

 or die ("Could not search");
 $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
 if($count == 0){
    $output = 'There were no search results!';
 }
 else{
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $recipe = $row[recipe_name];
   $ingredient = $row[ingredient_name];
   $id = $row[ingredient_id];

   $output .= '<div>'.$recipe.' '.$ingredient.'</div>';
  }
 }
}
```

We don't understand why it won't work.

Comment: Your forgot the `$` before the variable names

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated `mysql_*` API use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements

Comment: Can you give me an example where I have done this? I have looked over the code so many times I feel blind when looking at it. And thanks for your time.

Comment: @user2304993: In your SQL string.  Additionally, you forgot to quote the indexers when fetching data from `$row`.

Comment: Example = `ingredient_name LIKE '%searchq%'` should be `ingredient_name LIKE '%$searchq%`

Comment: Thank you John Conde and RiggsFolly, I had completely forgotten that part. And to Jens, this is a school project due tomorrow, I will research mysqli for next time, thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following. It uses mysqli_* functions and a better structure for the query joins.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'your_password', 'your_database');
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

$output = '';
if (isset($_POST['work'])) {

    $searchq = $_POST['work'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);

    $sql = "
        SELECT ingredient_name, recipe_name, recipe_ingredients.*
        FROM recipe_ingredients
        INNER JOIN ingredients
        ON recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients.ingredient_id
        INNER JOIN recipes
        ON recipe_ingredients.recipe_id = recipes.recipe_id
        WHERE ingredient_name LIKE '%$searchq%' or recipe_name LIKE '%$searchq%'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($connection);
    }

     $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

     if ($count == 0) {
        $output = 'There were no search results!';
     } else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $recipe = $row[recipe_name];
            $ingredient = $row[ingredient_name];
            $id = $row[ingredient_id];

            $output .= '<div>'.$recipe.' '.$ingredient.'</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What a completely wonderful answer. The code you have posted works very well, except that the search now returns every row in the table, instead of those containing the word searched and that's no matter what I search? What could be the cause of this? Thank you so much for your well-written answer!

Comment: Comment out the line: $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq); and check if there is a problem there.

Comment: Try to check this: $searchq = $_POST['work']; echo 'Old searchname: '. $searchq.'<br />'; $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);  echo 'New searchname: '. $searchq.'<br />'; If first one is empty then it means that $_POST['work'] is empty so LIKE '%%' in sql query is matched against every row.

Comment: I had attached the name="work" in the wrong portion of my form and that's why it kept giving the full table. Thanks for all the great answers and help!

Answer (score 0):

First - it depends on what version of PHP you are using, as Jens pointed out mysql_* has been deprecated.

Second - it does not appear that you are connecting to your database.  You have to connect to your database first, then execute your query.

Check out this example on [PHP's website](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), it should help you out a lot.

Good luck!

Comment: Ah, I did not include the database connection part. It does connect fine to the database and as John correctly pointed out, I had forgotten $ in my %$searchq%. Such a stupid mistake to make. The search works now, or sort of. It sadly brings back way too much information, when searching for Tomato is gives back Pizza which, in our database has no Tomato in it. Could the query be incorrect? It just works when running it in phpmyadmin. 
And to the PHP version - This is a school project due tomorrow, there's very little time. But thanks for the information, I will try researching it for next time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you re searching for      "searchq" all the time  and you probably dont have a recipe by that name  and I would advise agajnst mysql_* funcs
     $output = '';
     if (isset($_POST['work'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['work'];
     $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#
   i","",$searchq);
      $query = mysql_query
     ("select ingredient_name, recipe_name,    recipe_ingredients.*
    from recipe_ingredients
     inner join ingredients inner join recipes
    on recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id =         ingredients.ingredient_id
      and recipe_ingredients.recipe_id =         recipes.recipe_id
      WHERE ingredient_name LIKE '%
     $searchq%' or recipe_name LIKE '%
     $searchq%'")

Comment: You would advice against it? What would you use instead then?  Cause as it is now, the query gives me every single row in the table and I do only want those with my searched word in.

Comment: In PHP recent versions of a PHP using the mysql extension throws a nasty warning as it is now deprecated. It works fine but an unsupported API is nt something you want to use. PDO is much better for easy OOP integration but you can  you can opt for mysqli for a smooth migration. Check this out  www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/

Comment: remove the extra space here... LIKE '%$searchq%' between your wild card and the variable

Comment: I can simply not find the extra space you're talking about? Will removing it stop the query showing me every single row in the table? Do you mean the line break between 'where ingredi...' and the line above? Also, this is a school project due tomorrow, so learning and adjusting to mysqli will come after hand it, but thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Ah, between the '%' and the '$', I have removed that, but the code sadly still returns every single row in the array instead of those containing the searched word.